# How to find hashmap keys whose values are the same with a hashset

Tags: scala, hashmap, hashset

i have a hashset that has ids like:

> d1, d2, d3

and a hashmap that has some variables as keys and ids as values :

> (c1,d2), (c2,d1), (c1,d1), (c1,d3)

What i want is to find the keys in the hashmap that have all the ids from the set as values and put them in another set.

For example, for the data above, the only key that i would put in the new set is c1. That's because afterwards i want to do some computations and i want to prevent any Nans. I am thinking about creating a function that computes it but i was wondering if there was an easier and fastest way in scala that i don't know. Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Why are there duplicate keys in HashMap?

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap can not containt distinct elements with same id e.g
Map((c1,d2), (c2,d1), (c1,d1), (c1,d3)) -> will become Map((c2,d1), (c1,d3)).

```
val set = Set("d1", "d2", "d3")
val arr = Array(("c1", "d2"), ("c2", "d1"), ("c1", "d1"), ("c1", "d3"))

arr.groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
  .filter(_._2.sorted.sameElements(set)).keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
val s = Set("d1", "d2", "d3")

val l = List(("c1", "d2"), ("c2", "d1"), ("c1", "d1"), ("c1", "d3"))

l.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).toSet).
  filter{ case (_, v) => (v intersect s) == s }.
  keys.toList
// res2: List[String] = List(c1)
```